# Read from a file of chars and print a file of integers

Tags: c, char, integer

In my fgetc.in file I have 9 and in the fgetc.out it shows 41 instead of 9. I am confused what is wrong in my code but I guess it is smth wrong with EOF.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
    FILE *in = fopen("fgetc.in", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("fgetc.out", "wt");

    char c;
    int a = 0;
    c = fgetc ( in );
    a = c - '0';
    while(c != EOF ){
        c = fgetc ( in );
        a = a * 10 + (c - '0');
    }
    fprintf(out, "%d" , a);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RussBear The argument to `atoi()` is a string, not a single character.

Comment: `c - '0'` is the correct way to convert a single digit to the corresponding integer.

Comment: You're right, I confused `char c` with `char* c` actually. I've never seen `c - '0'` before, thanks.

Comment: You probably have other characters (such as spaces or a newline) in your input file.  You don't do anything to avoid them, so they end up going into your a value computation is if they were digits.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the *previous* read character for `EOF` in the `while` condition. So after you read the last character in the file, you'll read another character and add it to `a`. That next character will be `EOF`, whose value is `-1`. So you'll calculate

```
a = 9 * 10 + (-1 - '0');
```

which is `41`.

You need to check for EOF after reading the character but before using it.

Also, `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`, since `char` might not be able to hold the `EOF` value. You need to declare `c` as `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *in = fopen("fgetc.in", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("fgetc.out", "wt");

    int c;
    int a = 0;
    while(1){
        c = fgetc ( in );
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        a = a * 10 + (c - '0');
    }
    fprintf(out, "%d" , a);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```